# "sind fernzuhalten" vs. "müssen ferngehalten werden"

Tags: difference, verb, rules

[image]

> Hunde sind von der Grünanlage fernzuhalten

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "fernzuhalten" und "ferngehalten"? Wieso nicht "Hunde müssen von der Grünanlage ferngehalten werden", der natürlicher für unsere Ohren klingt?

Comment: Spekuliere: Das Schild war zu klein. Andererseits, warum nicht "Hunde von Grünanlagen fernhalten" oder einfach "Hunde nicht auf's Grün !" (sonst rot) :-) ? Ernsthaft, es ginge beides, vielleicht fand der Aufsteller diese Version einfach amtlicher ...

Comment: "klingt natürlicher für unserre Ohren" ist höchst subjektiv. In der gesprochenen Sprache würde man sich vielleicht eher mit "müssen" ausdrücken, aber für Geschriebenes und speziell für Verbotsschilder gilt das nicht.

Comment: I’m not sure why you reverted my edit but your last sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

"fernzuhalten" ist simply the infinitive with "zu", like for example, "zu gehen". If the verb is separable the "zu" is inserted in between the separable parts. To give another example consider "hineingehen", which become "hineinzugehen".

"sein" + the infinitive with "zu" can be used to express what must be done to something as an order or law. This construction also exists in English.

> Hunde sind von der Grünanlage fernzuhalten
>
> Dogs are to be kept away from the lawn

Some more examples:

> Lautes Singen ist zu unterlassen.

> Die Gebühr ist unverzüglich zu bezahlen.

Such language is especially common in legal texts and might be considered to sound more authoritative. Maybe this is what the person that ordered the sign was going for... we cannot really say.

Comment: Der formale, nachschlagbare Begriff dafür ist [Gerundiv](https://dewiki.de/Lexikon/Imperativ_(Modus)#Gerundiv).